# React Server side rendering of CSS modules

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-style-loader

The current practice for CSS with React components seems to be using webpack's style-loader to load it into the page in.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import style from './style.css';

class MyComponent extends Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <div className={style.demo}>Hello world!</div>
        );
    }
}
```

By doing this the style-loader will inject a `<style>` element into the DOM. However, the `<style>` will not be in the virtual DOM and so if doing server side rendering, the `<style>` will be omitted. This cause the page to have [FOUC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content).

Is there any other methods to load [CSS modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules) that work on both server and client side?

Comment: You can try this postcss plugin: https://github.com/ctxhou/postcss-hash-classname . I found the style loader only limit to the webpack, so with this plugin, you can extract the css class name as a js object file. Then you can require this `style.js` and use the same code. Because this is a `.js` file, of course it can support server side rendering. You can check the repo to know more : )

Comment: The problem I'm looking to solve is to make webpack inject the CSS into the virtual DOM so server side rendering also has CSS packed. I don't think that one has anything related to this task?

Comment: You mean you don't want to create another css file and only want the webpack to help you inject it ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can have a look at the [isomorphic-style-loader](https://github.com/kriasoft/isomorphic-style-loader). The loader was specifically created to solve this kind of issues.

However for using this you have to use an `_insertCss()` method provided by the loader. The documentation details how to use it.

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 11):

You can use [`webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin`](https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin). This will create a independently redistributable stylesheet you can reference then from your documents.

Comment: that doesnt help with the combination of css modules and server side rendering

Answer (score 3):

For me, I am using the Webpack loader [css-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader) to implement CSS modules in isomorphic application.

On  server side, the webpack config will be like this:

```
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(css)$/,
        include: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, '../src'),
        ],
        use: [
          {
            // Interprets `@import` and `url()` like `import/require()` and will resolve them
            loader: 'css-loader/locals',
            options: {
              modules: true,
              localIdentName: '[name]__[local]--[hash:base64:5]'
            }
          },
        ],
      },
    ]
  }
```

On client side, the webpack config looks like this

```
          {
            // Interprets `@import` and `url()` like `import/require()` and will resolve them
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: true,
              localIdentName: '[name]__[local]--[hash:base64:5]'
            }
          },
```

Off course, if you are using SASS, you need to use `sass-loader` to compile scss to css, and `postcss-loader` can help to add the `autoprefixer`.

Comment: when mention sass, sass-loader, autoprefixer etc - do I also need to setup webpack to handle those for the server-side?

Comment: yes, you need to setup those up for server side as well.

Comment: Is there a way to do this using only one set of config - for example, creating a library which will be used for _either_ server- or client-side rendering? (Unknown at build time)