# Server-side rendering of CSS modules

Tags: reactjs, webpack, server-side-rendering, isomorphic-style-loader

I am going to import styles with **CSS Module** and make it work with server-side rendering. I tried the following methods but each one has its own caveat. What is the best possible way to `require('.style.scss')` if any side effects?

1. Using the [css-modules-require-hook](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules-require-hook):

   **Advantage**: Easy to configure. You just need to call the hook at the beginning of server code. You don't need to modify components.

   **Caveat**: It modifies the `require.extensions` global object, which is **deprecated**.
2. Using the [isomorphic-style-loader](https://github.com/kriasoft/isomorphic-style-loader):

   **Advantage**: No more hooks to `require.extensions`.

   **Caveat**: Wrapping components with HOCs that uses the React `Context`, which is an **experimental** API and likely to break in future releases of React.
3. Using the [webpack-isomorphic-tools](https://github.com/halt-hammerzeit/webpack-isomorphic-tools):

   **Advantage**: No dependency on `require.extensions` or `Context` (AFAIK).

   **Caveat**: Wrapping server inside webpack-isomorphic-tools instance. And can we please get rid of **webpack-assets.json**?
4. Bundling server with **Webpack**:

   **Advantage**: No more hooks or injections.

   **Caveat**: In development, it is very cumbersome to bundle everything whenever the code changes and even makes it **harder** to debug in a large bundled `.js` file. Not sure - you may need to pass a bundled `.js` to test runner.

**Disclaimer**:

- The advantages and caveats below are just my two cents, and actually I love all the libraries, plugins and approaches they took to solve the problem and really appreciate their efforts.
- I am not a native English speaker, please correct me if I misrepresent myself.

Comment: I answered the similar question in here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34615898/react-server-side-rendering-of-css-modules/56589817#56589817 Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I decided to hook the `require.extensions` in development. Probably it is not the best way, showing warning messages on console, like checksum mismatch, but in development mode, I can ignore it.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean about `require.extensions`??? I'm going through the same thing and am almost getting `css-modules-require-hook` working, but not sure if this is truly the right way to go.