# React server-side rendering vs webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, isomorphic-javascript

I'm new in server-side React rendering, and I can make simple isomorphic React applications with webpack for client side and Express for server side (through React of course). But now I have some trouble - I decided to use images in my project:

```
export default class JustImage extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <img src={require("just_image.png")} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

It code works like a charm for client, but my server side code when I try to render tell me this error:

```
just_image.png: Unexpected character '�'
```

As I understand, Node.js doesn't know anything about webpack loaders, so can't load image right. Because I'm new in React and server-side rendering at all I want to know if there are any standard ways to fix this problem - not images only, I use images(PNG/JPEG/JPG/ICO), SVG, SASS/LESS/CSS. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to solve the problem, AFAIK:

1. Use the `webpack` for your server code as well. In your webpack configuration for server, you can use the same loader you did for your client. For example, you can use `url-loader` or `file-loader` for image files.

   ```
   {
     test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
     loader: 'url-loader',
     options: {
       limit: 8192,
     },
   }
   ```
2. You can hack the `require.extensions` at the top of your server code.

   ```
   if (process.env === 'development') {
     require.extensions['.png'] = () => {}
   }
   ```

I posted a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42220913/server-side-rendering-of-css-modules) not getting an answer :)

Comment: Thanks for answer. But I don't understand how I can use webpack for server code as well. Please, give me some example.

Comment: The `start` script can be `webpack --watch --config config/your-server-config.js && babel-node dist/server.js`. For my personal project, I opted to go with the second option, because re-bundling the server code every time code changes takes some time and not suitable for development, I think. For sample code/configuration: https://github.com/ming-soon/mern-starter

Comment: But if you will use 2 option, your server-side code will be broken right?

Comment: No, it has no side effects, besides that you have add the above code at the very beginning of your server code.

Comment: Try googling for a react starter kit that uses SSR, and investigate the webpack configs, it's usually done this way.

Comment: @MingSoon if I add this 'require' and will use some image for src attribute of image tag my code will be broken

Comment: @Mateusz please give me link, I don't know what SSR means

Comment: @malcoauri in my case, it gives me some warnings on the console, which I can ignore in development mode. Warnings are about mismatched checksum. How does your code get broken? What happens exactly?

Comment: @MingSoon after mismatched checksum client code re-render DOM again

Answer (score 0):

I learned a lot about this by reading the [react-starter-kit](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/blob/master/tools/webpack.config.js) code, it is basically what Ming Soon told you, you have to compile your server side code with webpack, you will need multiple webpack configs.