# react reference stylesheet in css module

Tags: reactjs, css-modules

I have the following .scss file

```
div.topMenuIndex {
  ul {
    &:before {
      content: "☰";
      padding: .15em .25em;
      text-align: center;
      background: #ea764b;
      color: #f8d4c6;
    }   
  &.LoginStatus{
    background: azure;
  }
}
```

Now I import this into my react component

```
import styles from "./TopMenuIndex.scss";
```

When defining the component how do I refer to div.topMenuIndex.LoginStatus in my div element

Hello jim

Comment: Please check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42220913/server-side-rendering-of-css-modules) I asked a few days ago.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `className=""`

So in your case, put `<div className="topMenuIndex LoginStatus"></div>`

Comment: I want to refer to topMenuIndex and LoginStatus, if I say topMenuIndex then only topMenuIndex style will be applied?

Comment: If you use `className="topMenuIndex">`, then the `background: azure` won't be applied, because that requires the `LoginStatus` class to be on the div as well. At the moment it looks like you don't have any specific styling for `topMenuIndex` in your css. You could test this by adding a `background-color: red` and see that it is applied.

Comment: I need to have something like this
<div className = .topMenuIndex.LoginStatus>Hello jim</div>

Only thing is that I need to refer to this through the styles.<Name>

Comment: Can you try `<div className="topMenuIndex LoginStatus">Hello jim</div>`? If this is not what you're looking for, I may be misunderstanding your question.

Comment: This will not work, I need to provide something like
<div className = {styles.topMenuIndex.LoginStatus}/>

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. In this case I'm not sure, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The `styles` object will have all your classnames as key and corresponding `hash` as the value.

So your need to use `styles[<classname>]`

Example

```
<div className={`${styles[topMenuIndex]} ${styles[LoginStatus]}`} />
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend using [react-css-modules](https://github.com/gajus/react-css-modules) if you can. You will just need to wrap your component with a decorator, but using your styles will be so much easier.

Here's how

`npm i -S react-css-modules`

In YourComponent.js

`import CSSModules from 'react-css-modules'
import styles from "./TopMenuIndex.scss";`

Then somewhere down in your component you will just use them as names, but using styleName instead of className

`<div styleName="topMenuIndex LoginStatus">test</div>`

and you export your component like this at the end

`export default CSSModules(YourComponent, styles, { allowMultiple: true });`