# server & client className did not match

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, server-side-rendering, css-loader

So i am using webpack and css-loader with localIndentName for server side rendering my app with react. I am using css modules to import css for sepecific components. Now the problem is while importing styles in a component the server is returning the css mapped object inside a local key so server is unable to find styles.className while on the client side everything works fine.

this is my edited rules config for both server and client

```
{
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
            {
                loader: 'css-loader',
                options: {
                    modules: true,
                    localIdentName: '[local]__[hash:base64:4],
                    camelCase: true
                }
            }
        ],
}
```

this is server server is getting when i console log any imported style

```
[ [ 107,
    '',
    '' ],
  toString: [Function],
  i: [Function],
  locals: { 'class-name': 'class-name__3WnY' } ]
```

This is what my client is complaining

```
Warning: Prop `className` did not match. Server: "" Client: "class-name__3WnY"
```

Why such behavior?

Answer (score 1):

The error was caused by the incorrect loader in server side.

In server side, we should use

```
loader: 'css-loader/locals',
```

While in client side, we should use

```
loader: 'css-loader',
```

For the full webpack configuration, please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34615898/react-server-side-rendering-of-css-modules/56589817#56589817) I made before. Hope it helps.