# How to get Node.js to accept css imports?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, css-import

Is there any known way to get Node.js to accept css imports when running javascript files?

More specifically, is there a known way to get a React app (that imports css files to render pages) to run on a node.js server to render the app to a string upon request to a certain endpoint?

Comment: This may help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34615898/react-server-side-rendering-of-css-modules